# How to run notification in another broacast receiver in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have notification that needs to run all times on status bar.

So this notification function looks like below.

```
   private fun StepCountNotification(context: Context, stepCount: Int?) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val CHANNEL_ID = "my_app"
            val channel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "MyApp", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            )
            (context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
                channel
            )
            val decimal = DecimalFormat("#,###")
            val step = decimal.format(stepCount)

            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_new_alarm_icon)
                .setContentTitle("$step 걸음")
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setShowWhen(false)
                .build()
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        }
    }
```

And this is called on `Service()` since it needs to work on background.

However I realized that this service is working and after a while, it stops.

Device kills background work, I guess.

So I want to use `AlarmManager` to be run every 15minutes, and if notification is not showing I will call notification once again.

I write AlarmManager code as below:

```
 val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val repeatInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES
        val triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + repeatInterval
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            applicationContext,
            ALARM_REQ_CODE,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        )
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            triggerTime,
            repeatInterval,
            pendingIntent
        )
```

And BroadcastReceiver named `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` is added in androidmanifest.

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".BroadcastReceiver.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.chugnchunon.chungchunon_android.AlarmNotification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

In this alarmNotification broadcast receiver, I check notification and if not, show this.

```
 val mNotificationManager = context!!.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val statusNotifications = mNotificationManager.activeNotifications
        for(statusNotification in statusNotifications) {
            if(statusNotification.id != NOTIFICATION_ID) {
                StepCountNotification(context, todayTotalStepCount)
            }
        }
```

Problem is, as you can see below, StepCountNotification function is not called.

I tried to get it by putting this function in `companion object` but, this is calling `startForground` so it can't be in companion object.

And AlarmManager broadcastReceiver is not called at all, regardless of this above issue.

I've struggled this issue a long time, please help me.

[image]